# Oversampling images during inference

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

It is is a common practice in convolutional neural networks to oversample a given image during inference,

I.e to create a batch from different transformation of the same image (most common - different crops and mirroring), transfer the entire batch through the network and average (or another kind of reducing function) over the results to get a single prediction ([caffe example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/classifier.py#L54)),

How can this approach be implemented in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the [TF cnn tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/). In particular, the function [distorted_inputs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L140) does the image preprocessing step.
In short, there are a couple of TF functions in the `tf.image` package that help with distorting the images. You can use either them or regular numpy functions to create an extra dimension for the output, for which you can average the results:

Before:

```
input_place = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 256, 256, 3])
prediction = some_model(input_place)  # size: [None]
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={input_place: batch_of_images})
```

After:

```
input_place = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, NUM_OF_DISTORTIONS, 256, 256, 3])
prediction = some_model(input_place)  # make sure it is of size [None, NUM_DISTORTIONS]
new_prediction = tf.reduce_mean(prediction, axis=1)
new_batch = np.zeros(batch_size, NUM_OF_DISTORTIONS, 256, 256, 3)
for i in xrange(len(batch_of_images)):
  for f in xrange(len(distortion_functions)):
    new_batch[i, f, :, :, :] = distortion_functions[f](batch_of_images[i])

sess.run(new_prediction, feed_dict={input_place: new_batch})
```

Comment: These transformations are applied in **training** time, every image in a batch  is transformed once. What I am looking for is a way to pack multiple transformations of the same image together during inference.

Comment: I added an example code how to use the distortion functions in inference time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TF's image-related functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/image/). You could apply those transformations at test time to some input image, and stack all of them together to make a batch.

I imagine you could also do this using OpenCV or some other image processing tool. I don't see a need to do it in the computation graph. You could create the batches beforehand, and pass it through in `feed_dict`.